debian 12 with wifi card cannot access internet but can local network
here is my setup (old tablet on intel atom z3736f + usb wifi dognle, so no bios settings to manage wifi & whatever):
kolya@z3736f:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 046d:c31a Logitech, Inc. Comfort Wave 450
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0000:0538   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


and
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 veth4e20cf8
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 veth4e20cf8
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 veth4e20cf8
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 docker0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-d72298d3b38d
172.19.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker_gwbridge
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlxe84e0626b452
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlxe84e0626b452
192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 wlxe84e0626b452


and
kolya@z3736f:~$ sudo ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:2e:97:49:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br-d72298d3b38d: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:18:07:53:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-d72298d3b38d
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:18ff:fe07:533b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ec:f6:a6:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:ecff:fef6:a687/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: veth4e20cf8@if10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP group default 
    link/ether 46:8f:e8:6d:8d:e1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet 169.254.220.47/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global veth4e20cf8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::448f:e8ff:fe6d:8de1/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: wlxe84e0626b452: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e8:4e:06:26:b4:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.8/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global dynamic wlxe84e0626b452
       valid_lft 84714sec preferred_lft 84714sec
    inet6 fe80::945d:a4ab:e302:a537/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


and finally
kolya@z3736f:~$ traceroute 1.1.1.1
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  z3736f.local (169.254.220.47)  3061.816 ms !H  3061.713 ms !H  3061.659 ms !H


i googled and read a few similar topics on stackoverflow but all of them got self-solved in some mysterious way after reboot or alike.
i think the reason is not having route added automatiocally for addresses like 0.0.0.0 in first position for wifi card.
for example here is results of routes from my another pc with ubuntu 22
➜  ~ sudo route -n    
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp34s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlxe84e0626b452
10.0.3.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 lxcbr0


so the question is how do I make it work by default (add route lines) or how to add new static lines in routes for my wifi card (no matter what usb port i plug it into) ?

If you use NetworkManager, check if "Never Use this network for default route" is checked for that connection
